# When do you use gridsearchcv vs. k-fold in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

When would you use gridsearchcv vs. k-fold? Does gridsearchcv automatically perform k-fold via the CV parameter?

example of gridsearch implementation:

```
GridSearchCV(svc_gc, param_grid=parameter_grid, cv=10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, GridSearchCV performs k-fold cross-validation, specified by the `cv` parameter. 
If the `cv` parameter is an integer, it represents the number of folds for k-fold cross-validation.

You might want to have a look at the reference as well: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) does perform a K-Fold cross validation, where the number of folds is specified by its `cv` parameter. If it is not specified, it applied a 5-fold cross validation by default.

Essentially they serve different purposes. Or better said, `GridSearchCV` can be seen of an extension of applying just a [`K-Fold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html), which is the way to go in the case of wanting to perform a hyper-parameter search over a predefined grid of parameters.